# type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

{id: 67, exercise_name: Exercise 1 (B), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch1-B.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch1-B.pdf%7D), {id: 92, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (A), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-A.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-A.pdf%7D), {id: 93, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (B), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-B.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-B.pdf%7D), {id: 94, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (C), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-C.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-C.pdf%7D), {id: 95, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (D), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-D.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-D.pdf%7D), {id: 96, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (E), exercise_solution: [https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-E.pdf}](https://odishacollege.in/elements/11th/ch14-E.pdf%7D), {id: 97, exercise_name: Exercise 14 (F), exercise_solution: https://odishacollege.in/

I/flutter (10602): API Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

i am trying to call api but i am getting this error

**Here is the Model**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Model_List {
  static List<BookData>? subjects = [];
}

class BookData {
  List<Allbooks>? allbooks;

  BookData({
    this.allbooks,
  });

  BookData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['allbooks'] != null) {
      allbooks = <Allbooks>[];
      json['allbooks'].forEach((v) {
        allbooks!.add(new Allbooks.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.allbooks != null) {
      data['allbooks'] = this.allbooks!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  BookData copyWith({
    List<Allbooks>? allbooks,
  }) {
    return BookData(
      allbooks: allbooks ?? this.allbooks,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'allbooks': allbooks!.map((x) => x?.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory BookData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return BookData(
      allbooks: map['allbooks'] != null ? List<Allbooks>.from((map['allbooks'] as List<int>).map<Allbooks?>((x) => Allbooks.fromMap(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),) : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson2() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory BookData.fromJson2(String source) => BookData.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() => 'BookData(allbooks: $allbooks)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant BookData other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      listEquals(other.allbooks, allbooks);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => allbooks.hashCode;
}

class Allbooks {
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? bookPdfUrl;
  List<Chapters>? chapters;

  Allbooks({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.bookPdfUrl,
    this.chapters,
  });

  Allbooks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    bookPdfUrl = json['book_pdf_url'];
    if (json['chapters'] != null) {
      chapters = <Chapters>[];
      (json['chapters'] as List).forEach((v) {
        chapters!.add(new Chapters.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['book_pdf_url'] = this.bookPdfUrl;
    if (this.chapters != null) {
      data['chapters'] = this.chapters!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  Allbooks copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? title,
    String? bookPdfUrl,
    List<Chapters>? chapters,
  }) {
    return Allbooks(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      bookPdfUrl: bookPdfUrl ?? this.bookPdfUrl,
      chapters: chapters ?? this.chapters,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'bookPdfUrl': bookPdfUrl,
      'chapters': chapters!.map((x) => x?.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Allbooks.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Allbooks(
      id: map['id'] != null ? map['id'] as String : null,
      title: map['title'] != null ? map['title'] as String : null,
      bookPdfUrl: map['bookPdfUrl'] != null ? map['bookPdfUrl'] as String : null,
      chapters: map['chapters'] != null ? List<Chapters>.from((map['chapters'] as List<int>).map<Chapters?>((x) => Chapters.fromMap(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),) : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson2() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Allbooks.fromJson2(String source) => Allbooks.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Allbooks(id: $id, title: $title, bookPdfUrl: $bookPdfUrl, chapters: $chapters)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Allbooks other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      other.id == id &&
      other.title == title &&
      other.bookPdfUrl == bookPdfUrl &&
      listEquals(other.chapters, chapters);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
      title.hashCode ^
      bookPdfUrl.hashCode ^
      chapters.hashCode;
  }
}

class Chapters {
  int? id;
  int? chapterNumber;
  String? chapterTitle;
  List<Exercises>? exercises;

  Chapters({
    this.id,
    this.chapterNumber,
    this.chapterTitle,
    this.exercises,
  });

  Chapters.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    chapterNumber = json['chapter_number'];
    chapterTitle = json['chapter_title'];
    if (json['exercises'] != null) {
      exercises = <Exercises>[];
      (json['exercises'] as List).forEach((v) {
        exercises!.add(new Exercises.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['chapter_number'] = this.chapterNumber;
    data['chapter_title'] = this.chapterTitle;
    if (this.exercises != null) {
      data['exercises'] = this.exercises!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  Chapters copyWith({
    int? id,
    int? chapterNumber,
    String? chapterTitle,
    List<Exercises>? exercises,
  }) {
    return Chapters(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      chapterNumber: chapterNumber ?? this.chapterNumber,
      chapterTitle: chapterTitle ?? this.chapterTitle,
      exercises: exercises ?? this.exercises,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'chapterNumber': chapterNumber,
      'chapterTitle': chapterTitle,
      'exercises': exercises!.map((x) => x?.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Chapters.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Chapters(
      id: map['id'] != null ? map['id'] as int : null,
      chapterNumber: map['chapterNumber'] != null ? map['chapterNumber'] as int : null,
      chapterTitle: map['chapterTitle'] != null ? map['chapterTitle'] as String : null,
      exercises: map['exercises'] != null ? List<Exercises>.from((map['exercises'] as List<int>).map<Exercises?>((x) => Exercises.fromMap(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),) : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson2() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Chapters.fromJson2(String source) => Chapters.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Chapters(id: $id, chapterNumber: $chapterNumber, chapterTitle: $chapterTitle, exercises: $exercises)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Chapters other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      other.id == id &&
      other.chapterNumber == chapterNumber &&
      other.chapterTitle == chapterTitle &&
      listEquals(other.exercises, exercises);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
      chapterNumber.hashCode ^
      chapterTitle.hashCode ^
      exercises.hashCode;
  }
}

class Exercises {
  int? id;
  String? exerciseName;
  String? exerciseSolution;

  Exercises({
    this.id,
    this.exerciseName,
    this.exerciseSolution,
  });

  Exercises.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    exerciseName = json['exercise_name'];
    exerciseSolution = json['exercise_solution'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['exercise_name'] = this.exerciseName;
    data['exercise_solution'] = this.exerciseSolution;
    return data;
  }

  Exercises copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? exerciseName,
    String? exerciseSolution,
  }) {
    return Exercises(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      exerciseName: exerciseName ?? this.exerciseName,
      exerciseSolution: exerciseSolution ?? this.exerciseSolution,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'exerciseName': exerciseName,
      'exerciseSolution': exerciseSolution,
    };
  }

  factory Exercises.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Exercises(
      id: map['id'] != null ? map['id'] as int : null,
      exerciseName: map['exerciseName'] != null ? map['exerciseName'] as String : null,
      exerciseSolution: map['exerciseSolution'] != null ? map['exerciseSolution'] as String : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson2() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Exercises.fromJson2(String source) => Exercises.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Exercises(id: $id, exerciseName: $exerciseName, exerciseSolution: $exerciseSolution)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Exercises other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      other.id == id &&
      other.exerciseName == exerciseName &&
      other.exerciseSolution == exerciseSolution;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ exerciseName.hashCode ^ exerciseSolution.hashCode;
}
```

Here is the api call function

```
class ApiCall {
 static Future<List<BookData>> loadData() async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  try {
    final res = await dio.get(Constants.subject_api);
    final responseBody = res.data;
   print("API Response: $responseBody");
   // final all_data =  BookData.fromJson(jsonDecode(responseBody) as Map<String,dynamic>).toString();
   final all_data =  jsonDecode(responseBody);

    // Model_List.subjects = List.from(all_data as Iterable)
    //   .map((e) => BookData.fromJson(e))
    //   .toList();
          Model_List.subjects!.forEach((element) {
        Model_List.subjects!.add(BookData.fromJson2(element as String));
      });
       Model_List.subjects = List.from(all_data as Iterable)
        .map<BookData>((item) => BookData.fromJson2(item))
        .toList();
    print("Data processed successfully");
    return Model_List.subjects!;
  } catch (error) {
    print("API Error: $error");
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to propagate it to the caller
  }
}
}
```

I have tried a lot things but not a single works here

Answer (score 0):

You have already used *JsonDecode* on the response body (it becomes a Map) so you can't use **BookData.fromJson2** on it again because this method awaits a *String*. The solution is to use **BookData.fromJson** instead. You don't even have to use *as String* on it if you have the right type.